# How to uninstall a program whose content already deleted?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I've accidentally deleted an installed program's folder in the `C:\Program Files` folder (it's for an Autodesk product). If I go to the Windows uninstaller tool, the program isn't listed there any more.

I tried to run the installer for that program again but it thinks the program is still there and won't let me install it.

How do I clean everything up so I can install it again?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows Installer Cleanup utility lets you delete entries from Programs and Features (Add/Remove Programs in XP). However it's no longer available from Microsoft and has been replaced by the [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed).

You can still get the older utility [elsewhere](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_installer_cleanup_utility.html).

Comment: I had the same problem as OP, but strangely enough, every program except the ones whose folder I deleted showed up in the troubleshooter!

Answer (score 4):

If you have already deleted the folder from the C: drive then use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to remove it from the list of installed programs, and fix your registry by running CCleaner after that. It will not show up any more.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any other Autodesk software installed which would need extensive reconfiguration, you could follow the steps outlined at [Autodesk Support](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/installation-activation-licensing/get-ready/remove-products/remove-windows-products), specifically from **Delete remaining Autodesk product files and folders** onwards:

> **Warning**: The following steps instruct you to delete folders at locations that would affect all installed Autodesk products. These
>   steps assume you have previously uninstalled all Autodesk products and
>   related peripherals and that it is safe to remove those folders.
>
> 1. In Windows Explorer, locate and delete the installation folder for each Autodesk product that was uninstalled in the previous procedures.
>      For example:
>
>    ```
>        C:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2015
>        C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016
>    ```
> 2. Delete the following folder:
>
>    ```
>        C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared
>    ```
>
>    *Note*: These locations may be different if your operating system is configured to store the Program Files folder on a drive other than
>      C, or if you installed your Autodesk product to another drive and
>      folder name.
> 3. Delete the following user profile folders (substitute your login name for %username%):
>
>    **Windows 7**
>
>    ```
>        C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk
>        C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Autodesk
>        C:\Users\Public\Documents\Autodesk
>        C:\ProgramData\Autodesk
>    ```
>
>    **Windows XP**
>
>    ```
>        C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\ Application Data\Autodesk
>        C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Autodesk
>        C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Autodesk
>    ```
>
> Windows 7: Depending on your system settings, Windows Explorer may not
>   automatically display all the subfolders under the Users folder. If
>   you cannot find these folders, copy and paste the above folder
>   locations into the Windows Explorer address bar.