# How to uninstall a program if I accidently deleted it from "C cleaner" programs list?

Tags: windows-10, ccleaner

In tools feature of C cleaner program, we can delete any program from "program lists" without uninstalling it.

I deleted one system program accidentally through C cleaner software. If I go to the Windows uninstaller tool, the program isn't listed there any more. Now I want to uninstalled that program. So how? I feel my question is above the level of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/360984/how-to-uninstall-a-program-whose-content-already-deleted).

OS: Windows 10.

Comment: "deleted one system program" How, exactly?

Comment: Reinstall the software and uninstall it properly instead of using malware infected CCLeaner

Comment: CCleaner is not malware infected.

Comment: @MichaelBevans - CCleaner for a period of time was infected with a malicious payload.  It's unnecessary software that is published by a company that cannot be trusted in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would reinstall the program if possible. Then uninstall it properly from the Programs/Apps list within Settings app on Windows 10.

If you are unable to obtain the binary, I've used uninstall tools such as Revo (might be a paid feature), which you can select a directory where some files of an application are located. Revo or similar program will find any related files, then list them for you to have the option to delete them.

Comment: Any free tools?